# Transform group by object into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I'm having an issue with R.
I have a group by object, created using `dplyr` package's `group_by()`, and need to get a dataframe out of it.
For instance, if what i have is:

```
Group 1: column1
0
0
0
0

Group 2: column 2
1
1
1
1
```

I need to get a dataframe as an output that looks like the following:

```
Column 1 column 2
0          1
0          1
0          1
0          1
```

Any ideas on how to do it in R?
Any help will be highly welcomed.

Comment: What is a "group by object"? Is this from a particular package? Could you share your "group by" object in a reproducible format, e.g., with `dput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be to do this:

```
df <- data.frame(groupByObjectName)
```

Comment: That would only be true if `groupByObjectName` were a two element list with named vectors. Even then I'm pretty sure that check.names would have gotten rid of those space in the names.